# modal pop up after clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, modal-dialog

I have a table (an album's tracklist) which has a column of buttons, what i want to do is that when you press a button, a modal pops up with the respective lyrics. i need to incorporate javascript and i need it to be responsive. help would be much appreciated.

**note:**
I've only incorporated the code for the table. If you believe that it would be more helpful to publish the code for the entire page please do tell me.

```css
table {
    width: 110%;
    text-align: left;
}

td {
    font-family: fantasy;
    font-size: 1.18em;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="tracklist">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="no">1.</td>
                                    <td class="title">Sherane a.k.a Master Splinter's Daughter</td>
                                    <td><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></td>
                                    <td class="duration">4:33</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="no">2.</td>
                                    <td class="title">Bitch, Don't Kill My Vibe</td>
                                    <td><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></td>
                                    <td class="duration">5:10</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="no">3.</td>
                                    <td class="title">Backseat Freestyle</td>
                                    <td><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></td>
                                    <td class="duration">3:32</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="no">4.</td>
                                    <td class="title">The Art of Peer Pressure</td>
                                    <td><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></td>
                                    <td class="duration">5:24</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="no">5.</td>
                                    <td class="title">Money Trees (feat. Jay Rock)</td>
                                    <td><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></td>
                                    <td class="duration">6:26</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="no">6.</td>
                                    <td class="title">Poetic Justice (feat. Drake)</td>
                                    <td><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></td>
                                    <td class="duration">5:00</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="no">7.</td>
                                    <td class="title">Good Kid</td>
                                    <td><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></td>
                                    <td class="duration">3:34</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="no">8.</td>
                                    <td class="title">M.A.A.D City (feat. MC Eiht)</td>
                                    <td><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></td>
                                    <td class="duration">5:50</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="no">9.</td>
                                    <td class="title">Swimming Pools (Drank) [Extended Version]</td>
                                    <td><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></td>
                                    <td class="duration">5:13</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="no">10.</td>
                                    <td class="title">Sing About Me, I'm Dying of Thirst</td>
                                    <td><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></td>
                                    <td class="duration">12:03</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="no">11.</td>
                                    <td class="title">Real (feat. Anna Wise)</td>
                                    <td><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></td>
                                    <td class="duration">7:23</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="no">12.</td>
                                    <td class="title">Compton (feat. Dr. Dre)</td>
                                    <td><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button></td>
                                <td class="duration">4:08</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Yes please. Do so. Post the modal HTML, CSS and the best JS code you have already. Also, don't ask multiple questions, you have a CSS (responsiveness) issue or a JS issue?

Comment: You can use Modal's from Bootstrap to achieve this - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

Answer (score 0):

you can create a wrapper on top of your page.

```
<div class="modal" id="lyrics1">
  <div class="lyrics1"> lirics goes here </div>
</div>
<button class="lyricsPreview" onclick="openModal()"></button>  

<script>
 const lyrics1 = document.getElementById('lyrics1');
 function openModal(){
   lyrics1.style.display = "block";
 }
</script>
```

the button is clicked, and the modal is displayed. You can style the modal as you like, just remember to add in the css none to have it hidden by default.

```
.modal{
  display: none;
}
```